# Can i upgrade my AMD A4-4300M chip?

Tags: cpu, amd-cpu

I'm using laptop HP 4545s and it's using AMD A4-4300M chip.
I've upgrade ssd driver and add new ram to my laptop but it seem my cpu, but it seems my cpu chip is always overloaded. Can I able to upgrade this chip, and which chip line fits my laptop.

Thanks for reading and supporting me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would *appear* the HP 4545s does not have soldered CPUs, but has socketed CPUs based on the information I saw on this [website](http://www.cpu-upgrade.com/mb-HP/ProBook_4545s.html).

However, I would take the information with a grain of salt.  I would open up the laptop and check if the CPU is soldered or socketed.  Just because it was socketed at one point in time doesnt mean they didnt change it to soldered at another.

Of the three CPUs listed as compatible, one is the same you have and the second one is not really an upgrade.  The last one, a A8-4500M quad-core would be a decent upgrade.  However, reading the comments, upgrading the CPU can cause issues, which may or may not be fixed with BIOS upgrades.

I did some quick browsing and it looks like you can find them pretty cheap, especially from [China](https://www.ebay.com/p/1963010255?iid=282363800652&chn=ps&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=711-117182-37290-0&mkcid=2&itemid=282363800652&targetid=539174368795&device=c&mktype=pla&googleloc=9008490&poi=&campaignid=6470552772&mkgroupid=81274341727&rlsatarget=aud-622524042958:pla-539174368795&abcId=1139336&merchantid=112227723&gclid=CjwKCAiA8ejuBRAaEiwAn-iJ3ugp-UF7Rl_vdgTv4tdH-NRt3PiRx7twi5Kp8VQHiED1PaKXSxzaBhoCeW0QAvD_BwE).  If you do indeed have a CPU socket, I think it would be worth the upgrade.  There would be a visible increase in speed in multithreaded applications.  And if it doesnt work, you can put the original CPU back in.  Then, theoretically, you could return the CPU.  In my opinion, its worth the effort for a few dollars.

Comment: Thank you very much! Hope you have a good day :)